# How to connect to Adaptive Server Anywhere 7 (SQL Anywhere) using PHP and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, sybase-asa

I am building an application which needs to pull data from an in house database.  This database is Adaptive Server Anywhere Version 7.  It is running on a Windows 2003 Server with Apache and PHP.  The server houses both the web application and the database.  I do not need to connect to database from the outside.

How do I get access to this database in a PHP application.  I have only really worked with MySQL in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If good enough, create a odbc-dsn (mind wow64) and use it to tie php to your db.